# Ruby On Rails Vs Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

i used PHP for my web development, until recently when i started using python framework Django, i enjoy the experience, 
but had a chat with my friend and he started saying this and that about me switching to Rail, even with all
my effort trying to explain to him that the are vitually alike he kept echoing rails.

If anyone is actually better than the other, please that i will like to know
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your projects. Rails has a bigger community IMHO, great screencasts. Django has great stuff out of the box. Whereas rails has gems for every task you require and they are always changing (which is good and bad; might be hard to keep up)

Django has an out of the box administration panel and a great templating library.
You can use python egg as far as I know, and other python libraries.

I'd give Django a go first to so as to finish something, but then in the long run using Rails could be of benefit.